# Russian characters from hex to string utf8 - getting the wrong characters

Tags: php, hex, ascii, cyrillic

I am trying to pass hex-encoded parameters to an image-creating script. All documents are in utf8. Everything is fine until I go through the string in a loop. See the minimized example:

```
$string="ABCDЯ";

for($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++) {
 echo $string[$i]."<br>"
}
```

gives the output:

```
A
B
C
D
�
```

instead of

```
A
B
C
D
Я
```

Why is that? Since I want to analyze the characters in the string, it fails at this point, because all Russian characters end up as �.

Answer (score 1):

In [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.details):

> The string in PHP is implemented as an array of bytes and an integer
>   indicating the length of the buffer. It has no information about how
>   those bytes translate to characters, leaving that task to the
>   programmer.

So, you're iterating `$string` byte by byte. If a character is not encoded with single-byte, the correct result won't be returned.

> Given that PHP does not dictate a specific encoding for strings, one
>   might wonder how string literals are encoded. For instance, is the
>   string "á" equivalent to "\xE1" (ISO-8859-1), "\xC3\xA1" (UTF-8, C
>   form), "\x61\xCC\x81" (UTF-8, D form) or any other possible
>   representation? The answer is that string will be encoded in whatever
>   fashion it is encoded in the script file.

You can use [mb_substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) to get a character when iterating `$string`.

```
<?php
$string = 'ABCDЯ';

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
    echo mb_substr($string, $i, 1, 'UTF-8') . '<br>';
}
```